# How to stop boot process on embedded system?

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I have an IP camera (Xiaomi Mijia 360° 1080P – Series: MJSXJ02CM) and after updating the firmware, it has been unable to work anymore! So I decided to tear it down to find the reason.

Front side:

[image: Front side]

Back Side:

[image: Back Side]

It is an embedded system with U-Boot operating system 2015.01. I successfully connected to it via USB-UART and PuTTY. However, I can not interact with it from the command line, the process is automatic and continuous which can not be interfered with Ctrl + C (For details of this process, see [HERE](https://justpaste.it/5naq5)).

What are the steps to stop the startup process and enter the command line prompt..?

Comment: *"It is an embedded system with U-Boot operating system"* -- No, U-Boot is just a boot program.  In this case U-Boot loads a Linux kernel, so Linux is the OS.  I've seen a similar camera that apparently has a U-Boot that has been customized to expect a special keystroke to stop autoboot.  But in your case, the default environment is active, and **bootdelay** seems to have a negative value, and U-Boot skips prompt altogether.

Comment: *"env_offset=0x4F000 env_size=0x1000"* -- U-Boot is reporting where its environment is.  Determine which memory chip this is for, remove the chip from the board, and fix up the environment so that it has a correct CRC32 and contains a long **bootdelay**.

Comment: The manufacturer has a license obligation to provide the sources for their version of U-Boot to you on request, so you can get those and see if there are any mechanisms left in.  If not, or if that process drags out, there's a standard-looking 8-pin flash chip in your photo you could possibly access by holding the processor in reset and tapping into the lines with an MCU board running flashrom's delegate, or definitely access by transplanting out of the system.  You can also get the docs on the SoC and see if there are other boot modes you could choose.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for your support! I will try to take the chip out of the board to see what the results will look like!

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your support! In a negative way, I can not expect responsibility from Chinese manufacturers, as you see in the picture, they even covered the SoC part number. However, I will try to take the flash chip out to see how the results will look like!

Comment: @ChrisStratton -- MStar and manufacturers that use its chips have a history of ignoring the GPL.

Comment: Note that this u-boot enables the watchdog with a 60s timeout. If you don't service the WDT, it will reset the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the boot procedure by pressing and hold down ENTER key while you power on the camera:

```
SF: Detected nor0 with total size 16 MiB
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   Net Initialization Skipped
No ethernet found.
SigmaStar # 
SigmaStar # 
SigmaStar # 
SigmaStar # 
SigmaStar #
```